# Issue when using wordpress on Arvixe hosting

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, hosting

I am having some trouble when using wordpress which is hosted by Arvixe. When ever I upload a file like a csv to a plugin it just gives me this error below:

HTTP Error 403.0 - Forbidden
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Most likely causes:
This is a generic 403 error and means the authenticated user is not authorized to view the page.

Things you can try:
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     FastCgiModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    PHP via FastCGI (*.php)
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      http://discountwomensjewelry.com:80/wp-admin/tools.php?page=wooexim-import&action=preview
Physical Path      E:\HostingSpaces\aaroncm\discountwomensjewelry.com\wwwroot\wp-admin\tools.php
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

I don't understand, because Arvixe is supposed to be a top hosting company.

I have submitted a support ticket to them hours and hours ago , but no reply yet. So I was hoping maybe someone here could tell me how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: And PLEASE don't ban this question just because I posted a link, could you just remove it if it's against the rules?

Comment: Have you test to change to FastCGI option on your control panel? You receive late reply because maybe they still experience the issue, just check out http://bit.ly/1H9Zy5K and http://bit.ly/1VNo3w6

Comment: Arvixe Hosting is very very very a horrible and irresponsible company, it;s only money trap. They squeeze money. my advice is change hosting company as soon as posible

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error try changing the file perms to 755 recursively on the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to the installation page such as:

www.website.com/wp-admin/install.php